# Manga/manhwa about a guy with water powers, a secret society, and a secret training island

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this story a bit then left and forgot its name.

There is a guy who discovers that he has water-controlling powers when he is attacked on a rooftop near a water tank, and he suddenly creates a giant water ball to drown them. Then he gets a friend with yellow lighting powers, who wears a weird costume and takes him to a secret island, sort of like the Nest in *Jungle Juice* through a plane with his other friend. After reaching the island, they suddenly join a hide-and-seek or tag-type game, which the main character misunderstands for a terrorist attack.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the main character's hair?